# MySQL full-text search is slow as table grows

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

MySQL simple fulltext search is getting slower as table size grows.

When I run a query like below using fulltext index, it takes about 90 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT * FROM project_fulltext_indices WHERE match(search_text) against ('abcdefghijklmnopq') limit 1;
```

The tables have about 4G rows, and the size is about 9.4GB.

The table mainly contains source code(English).

It used to be much faster when the table is much smaller.

Is there any idea how to improve the performance ?

Comment: SELECT * should RARELY be used.  Get only the columns of data you NEED.  When the mountain of data grows, it will take longer to find the details.  Some things never change.

Comment: This URL may be helpful for you.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-improve-database-searches-with-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04   Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql indexes.
It is like a placing a bookmark in a book.

Create an index in the `project_fulltext_indices`

take note. avoid using mysql functions in querying a large data for faster result.
If I am correct mysql indexes doesn't working then mysql function is used.

Comment: The "search_text" field have fulltext index.

Answer (score 0):

I created the copy of table by creating the same schema, inserting all the rows, and creating the fullt-text index. The rename the copied table to original table.

After that, the speed of full-text search becomes 50ms from 90seconds.(more than 1000 times faster.)

I also tried to run "OPTIMIZE TABLE project_fulltext_indices", but it takes long time. I waited more than 1 hour, and gave up. And worse, while optimizing the table, the table looks being locked and the running web services stopped working.